# How to enter variable content into form field

Tags: javascript, forms, field

I am attempting to place the selected image file number (from a slideshow) into a form field with the onClick trigger but I get the console message Uncaught TypeError: Property 'value' of object # is not a function.

My function is;

```
function ifExistsWrite(str) {
    var re = new RegExp('\"', 'gi');
    var newstr = str.replace(re, '&quot;');
    if (newstr != "")
        document.write(newstr + "<br>");
}

function fileNumber() {
    document.getElementById(id = "item_number").value(ifExistsWrite("%CAPTIONTITLE%"));
}
```

And I am calling the value like this;

`<form>
          <input type="hidden" id="item_number" name="%CAPTIONTITLE%" value="">
          <button type="submit" onclick="fileNumber();">Large</button>
 </form>`

I must confess that my 14 yr old son is better at javascript than me but he can't see the problem either.

Comment: Dont put id="item_number", as all is required is the string of the ID: document.getElementById("item_number");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***console message Uncaught TypeError: Property 'value' of object # is not a function.***

Use

```
document.getElementById("item_number").value= ifExistsWrite("%CAPTIONTITLE%");
```

Problems, `value` is a property.

Additionally, You should return some value

```
function ifExistsWrite(str) {
    var re = new RegExp('\"', 'gi');
    var newstr = str.replace(re, '&quot;');
    if (newstr != "")
        document.write(newstr + "<br>");

    //Retrun your value
    return newstr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The value still does not populate the form field but I now only get the message; event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. in the console window of Chrome. I do not know what this means or how to comply.

Comment: @edwind, This is only a warning: your code still works, but probably won't work in the future as the method is deprecated.

Comment: OK @Satpal, I get that the comment in itself is not a problem but the code is NOT working in that the 'value' is not being carried forward into the Form field. Does anyone have any more suggestions please?

Comment: @edwind, see it works. http://jsfiddle.net/zBE2D/. As its an hidden field, use developer tools to see it

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. The problem I have is the output does not show the result. e.g. Another field in the for is `<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="36x24">` and the output shows the value 36x24 but with this field 'item_number' that the function should return, there is nothing shown in the output. This is what I mean by 'not working'.

Comment: Thanks again @Satpal I now know that what yopu said was correct. I was stupidly trying to return a value that did not exist. All is now working fine thank you.